# Mosquitto OpenSSL handshake failure.

Tags: openssl, centos, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a Mosquitto 1.4.4 broker hosted in CentOs 6.7.

By following mosquitto docs 
(http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-tls-7.html) and
[How do you set up encrypted mosquitto broker like a webpage which has https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657319/how-do-you-set-up-encrypted-mosquitto-broker-like-a-webpage-which-has-https)

I tried to enable encrypted connection between client and mosquitto broker, and got the broker up and running with TLS enabled.

```
mosquitto version 1.4.4 (build date 2015-09-24 08:08:55+0000) starting
Config loaded from mosquitto.conf.
Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883
```

After distributing the certificate authority certificate ( `ca.crt` ) , i tried to run a test round with `mosquitto_pub` in lib_mosquitto, using the command

```
mosquitto_pub -h x.x.x.x -p 8883 -t topic -m message --cafile ca.crt
```

what i get in the mosquitto broker is

```
New connection from y.y.y.y on port 8883.
OpenSSL Error: error:140780E5:SSL routines:SSL23_READ:ssl handshake failure
Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

What could be the fix? Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: I wasnt so sure if the fault is with libmosquitto openssl client. I actually posted it here since there were no tags for mosquitto or mqtt on serverfault. My bad. 
Still i realize this is the wrong forum. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common cause of failure I've seen here is badly configured certificates. I'd suggest debugging with the openssl client. This should give you a better idea of where the problem lies.

```
openssl s_client -connect x.x.x.x:8883 -CAfile ca.crt
```

You could also try checking against a different server to make sure the client is working fine.

```
wget http://test.mosquitto.org/ssl/mosquitto.org.crt
mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org -p 8883 -t topic -m message --cafile mosquitto.org.crt
```

Comment: `openssl s_client` should be invoked with `-tls1 -servername <server name>` to ensure TLS and SNI are used. The lack of TLS and SNI causes problems in practice. See, for example, [Monitoring software depending on openssl not working on cloudflare ssl websites](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/monitoring-software-depending-on-openssl-not-working-on-cloudflare-ssl-websites-td60121.html) on the OpenSSL users mailing list. Also, you should not waste time with questions where the OP withholds essential information, like the server name. We can't check configurations or verify proposed fixes.

Comment: @ralight openssl client works fine. Problem should be with the libmosquitto client. Going to try out some other clients.

Comment: @jww I agree about it not being a programming question (I just answered automatically without thinking about where the question was), but the rest of your comment is unnecessary in this case - the server in question has only ever supported TLS, not SSL, and doesn't support SNI.