# MQTT server with SSL/TLS Error: Unable to load server key file

Tags: ssl, mqtt, tls1.2

I am trying to set up an MQTT broker with SSL. When I start the broker, I get this error:

```
1452342536: Error: Unable to load server key file "/home/ilab/mqtt/server/server.key". Check keyfile.
```

The following is my mosquitto.conf:

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
cafile /home/ilab/mqtt/CA/ca.crt
certfile /home/ilab/mqtt/server/server.crt
keyfile /home/ilab/mqtt/server/server.key
port 8883
tls_version tlsv1
```

I also followed the step mentioned in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657319/how-do-you-set-up-encrypted-mosquitto-broker-like-a-webpage-which-has-https) question. But still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Does the key have a password?

Comment: @hardillb Yes,  it has a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue and it seems like it got fixed by changing the permissions to read the file from: `-rw-------` to `-rw-r--r--` for the file `/etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt-server.key`

Steps:

- Navigate to the directory

```
cd /etc/mosquitto/certs
```

- List file permissions (-rw-------)

```
ls -l
```

- As root, change all users permission to read the file

```
sudo chmod a+r mqtt-server.key
```

- List file permissions again to see changes (now -rw-r--r--)

```
ls -l
```

- Restart the broker/server

```
sudo systemctl restart mosquitto
```

I not sure if this pose any security issue, but hope not. Planning on using authorization and encryption to access the server from the web.

Comment: Private keys should be readable by the smallest number of users as possible. This makes the file world readable which is not secure

Comment: Is that so even if I demand the clients to authenticate over a TLS connection? That is not good, will try some of the other solutions in this thread then.

Answer (score 4):

As @hardillb implies, try removing the password or start the broker manually.

Alternatively, if you're on Ubuntu then apparmor may be restricting access to those files. Try put them in `/etc/mosquitto/certs` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by providing the fullchain.pem instead of the chain.pem in the configuration.

Comment: how did you create fullpem ?  i have cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt_ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt_srv.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/mqtt_srv.pem files

Comment: can you please provide an example of fullchai configuration in mosquitto? tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can even try changing the name of server.crt to cert.pem and server .key to key.pem in the path mqtt/certs/
Also don't forget to change the path and file name in your code.